# How animate on exit of page (internal) with CSS

Tags: css

I have created a couple css animations and I am trying to make one play when you leave an internal page (go from `"#top"` to `"#bar1"`.

I have incorporated animations (as class) playing when the page enters but cant figure out how to play on exit.

- basically on my page I have 3 buttons and 3 bars.
- lets say we have button 1 2 and 3 each one corresponds with bar 1 2 and 3.
- on page start (top) all 3 bars are showing.
- if you press a button, the corresponding bar stays still and the rest of them will animate out.
- THEN if you press a button after that button that was animated out will animate IN and the current one standing will animate out

Again, I have the animate In part just fine

EDIT:

I guess what I'm asking is basically how to do this:

if href = 1{
animation play forwards
}else{
play animation backwards
}
for each bar

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your links were in a UL with the class .nav, the code can be something like this:

```
$("ul.nav li").click(function() {
    $("ul.nav li:not(this)").stop().fadeTo(250,0.5);
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(250,1);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

I am pretty new to js in html. I have put this code between <script> and </script> in the head. Now I am just wondering how to to call this script.